# Adding a wall with an opening Xbim

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I am looking to adjust the template project to add an opening for the door so the door will be flush with the wall system instead of appearing embedded in the skin of the wall any help would be very appreciated.

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Xbim.Common;
using Xbim.Common.Step21;
using Xbim.Ifc;
using Xbim.IO;
using Xbim.Ifc4.ActorResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.DateTimeResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.ExternalReferenceResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.PresentationOrganizationResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.GeometricConstraintResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.GeometricModelResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.GeometryResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.Interfaces;
using Xbim.Ifc4.Kernel;
using Xbim.Ifc4.MaterialResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.MeasureResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.ProductExtension;
using Xbim.Ifc4.ProfileResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.PropertyResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.QuantityResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.RepresentationResource;
using Xbim.Ifc4.SharedBldgElements;


namespace HelloWall
{
    class Program 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This sample demonstrates the minimum steps to create a compliant IFC model that contains a single standard case wall
        /// </summary>
        static int Main()
        {
            //first create and initialise a model called Hello Wall
            Console.WriteLine("Initialising the IFC Project....");
            using (var model = CreateandInitModel("HelloWall"))
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    IfcBuilding building = CreateBuilding(model, "Default Building");
                    IfcWallStandardCase wall = CreateWall(model, 4000, 300, 2400);

                    if (wall != null) AddPropertiesToWall(model, wall);
                    using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Add Wall"))
                    {
                        building.AddElement(wall);
                        txn.Commit();
                    }

                    if (wall != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Standard Wall successfully created....");
                            //write the Ifc File
                            model.SaveAs("HelloWallIfc4.ifc", IfcStorageType.Ifc);
                            Console.WriteLine("HelloWallIfc4.ifc has been successfully written");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Failed to save HelloWall.ifc");
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to initialise the model");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit to view the IFC file....");
            Console.ReadKey();
            LaunchNotepad("HelloWallIfc4.ifc");
            return 0;
        }

        private static void LaunchNotepad(string fileName)
        {
            Process p;
            try
            {

                p = new Process {StartInfo = {FileName = fileName, CreateNoWindow = false}};
                p.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}",
                          ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private static IfcBuilding CreateBuilding(IfcStore model, string name)
        {
            using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Create Building"))
            {
                var building = model.Instances.New<IfcBuilding>();
                building.Name = name;

                building.CompositionType = IfcElementCompositionEnum.ELEMENT;
                var localPlacement = model.Instances.New<IfcLocalPlacement>();                   
                building.ObjectPlacement = localPlacement;
                var placement = model.Instances.New<IfcAxis2Placement3D>();
                localPlacement.RelativePlacement = placement;
                placement.Location = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>(p=>p.SetXYZ(0,0,0));
                //get the project there should only be one and it should exist
                var project = model.Instances.OfType<IfcProject>().FirstOrDefault();
                project?.AddBuilding(building);
                txn.Commit();
                return building;                               
            }          
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up the basic parameters any model must provide, units, ownership etc
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="projectName">Name of the project</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IfcStore CreateandInitModel(string projectName)
        {
            //first we need to set up some credentials for ownership of data in the new model
            var credentials = new XbimEditorCredentials
            {
                ApplicationDevelopersName = "xbim developer",
                ApplicationFullName = "Hello Wall Application",
                ApplicationIdentifier = "HelloWall.exe",
                ApplicationVersion = "1.0",
                EditorsFamilyName = "Team",
                EditorsGivenName = "xbim",
                EditorsOrganisationName = "xbim developer"
            };
            //now we can create an IfcStore, it is in Ifc4 format and will be held in memory rather than in a database
            //database is normally better in performance terms if the model is large >50MB of Ifc or if robust transactions are required

            var model = IfcStore.Create(credentials, IfcSchemaVersion.Ifc4,XbimStoreType.InMemoryModel);

            //Begin a transaction as all changes to a model are ACID
            using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Initialise Model"))
            {

                //create a project
                var project = model.Instances.New<IfcProject>();
                //set the units to SI (mm and metres)
                project.Initialize(ProjectUnits.SIUnitsUK);
                project.Name = projectName;
                //now commit the changes, else they will be rolled back at the end of the scope of the using statement
                txn.Commit();
            }
            return model; 

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This creates a wall and it's geometry, many geometric representations are possible and extruded rectangular footprint is chosen as this is commonly used for standard case walls
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <param name="length">Length of the rectangular footprint</param>
        /// <param name="width">Width of the rectangular footprint (width of the wall)</param>
        /// <param name="height">Height to extrude the wall, extrusion is vertical</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static private IfcWallStandardCase CreateWall(IfcStore model, double length, double width, double height)
        {
            //
            //begin a transaction
            using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Create Wall"))
            {
                var wall = model.Instances.New<IfcWallStandardCase>();
                wall.Name = "A Standard rectangular wall";

                //represent wall as a rectangular profile
                var rectProf = model.Instances.New<IfcRectangleProfileDef>();
                rectProf.ProfileType = IfcProfileTypeEnum.AREA;
                rectProf.XDim = width;
                rectProf.YDim = length;

                var insertPoint = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>();
                insertPoint.SetXY(0, 400); //insert at arbitrary position
                rectProf.Position = model.Instances.New<IfcAxis2Placement2D>();
                rectProf.Position.Location = insertPoint;

                //model as a swept area solid
                var body = model.Instances.New<IfcExtrudedAreaSolid>();
                body.Depth = height;
                body.SweptArea = rectProf;
                body.ExtrudedDirection = model.Instances.New<IfcDirection>();
                body.ExtrudedDirection.SetXYZ(0, 0, 1);

                //parameters to insert the geometry in the model
                var origin = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>();
                origin.SetXYZ(0, 0, 0);
                body.Position = model.Instances.New<IfcAxis2Placement3D>();
                body.Position.Location = origin;

                //Create a Definition shape to hold the geometry
                var shape = model.Instances.New<IfcShapeRepresentation>();
                var modelContext = model.Instances.OfType<IfcGeometricRepresentationContext>().FirstOrDefault();
                shape.ContextOfItems = modelContext;
                shape.RepresentationType = "SweptSolid";
                shape.RepresentationIdentifier = "Body";
                shape.Items.Add(body);

                //Create a Product Definition and add the model geometry to the wall
                var rep = model.Instances.New<IfcProductDefinitionShape>();
                rep.Representations.Add(shape);                
                wall.Representation = rep;

                //now place the wall into the model
                var lp = model.Instances.New<IfcLocalPlacement>();
                var ax3D = model.Instances.New<IfcAxis2Placement3D>();
                ax3D.Location = origin;
                ax3D.RefDirection = model.Instances.New<IfcDirection>();
                ax3D.RefDirection.SetXYZ(0, 1, 0);
                ax3D.Axis = model.Instances.New<IfcDirection>();
                ax3D.Axis.SetXYZ(0, 0, 1);
                lp.RelativePlacement = ax3D;
                wall.ObjectPlacement = lp;


                // Where Clause: The IfcWallStandard relies on the provision of an IfcMaterialLayerSetUsage 
                var ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterialLayerSetUsage>();
                var ifcMaterialLayerSet = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterialLayerSet>();
                var ifcMaterialLayer = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterialLayer>();
                ifcMaterialLayer.LayerThickness = 10;
                ifcMaterialLayerSet.MaterialLayers.Add(ifcMaterialLayer);
                ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage.ForLayerSet = ifcMaterialLayerSet;
                ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage.LayerSetDirection = IfcLayerSetDirectionEnum.AXIS2;
                ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage.DirectionSense = IfcDirectionSenseEnum.NEGATIVE;
                ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage.OffsetFromReferenceLine = 150;

                // Add material to wall
                var material = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterial>();
                material.Name = "some material";
                var ifcRelAssociatesMaterial = model.Instances.New<IfcRelAssociatesMaterial>();
                ifcRelAssociatesMaterial.RelatingMaterial = material;
                ifcRelAssociatesMaterial.RelatedObjects.Add(wall);

                ifcRelAssociatesMaterial.RelatingMaterial = ifcMaterialLayerSetUsage;

                // IfcPresentationLayerAssignment is required for CAD presentation in IfcWall or IfcWallStandardCase
                var ifcPresentationLayerAssignment = model.Instances.New<IfcPresentationLayerAssignment>();
                ifcPresentationLayerAssignment.Name = "some ifcPresentationLayerAssignment";
                ifcPresentationLayerAssignment.AssignedItems.Add(shape);


                // linear segment as IfcPolyline with two points is required for IfcWall
                var ifcPolyline = model.Instances.New<IfcPolyline>();
                var startPoint = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>();
                startPoint.SetXY(0, 0);
                var endPoint = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>();
                endPoint.SetXY(4000, 0);
                ifcPolyline.Points.Add(startPoint);
                ifcPolyline.Points.Add(endPoint);

                var shape2D = model.Instances.New<IfcShapeRepresentation>();
                shape2D.ContextOfItems = modelContext;
                shape2D.RepresentationIdentifier = "Axis";
                shape2D.RepresentationType = "Curve2D";
                shape2D.Items.Add(ifcPolyline);
                rep.Representations.Add(shape2D); 
                txn.Commit();               
                return wall;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add some properties to the wall,
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">XbimModel</param>
        /// <param name="wall"></param>
        static private void AddPropertiesToWall(IfcStore model, IfcWallStandardCase wall)
        {
            using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Create Wall"))
            {
                CreateElementQuantity(model, wall);
                CreateSimpleProperty(model, wall); 
                txn.Commit(); 
            }
        }

        private static void CreateSimpleProperty(IfcStore model, IfcWallStandardCase wall)
        {
            var ifcPropertySingleValue = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertySingleValue>(psv =>
            {
                psv.Name = "IfcPropertySingleValue:Time";
                psv.Description = "";
                psv.NominalValue = new IfcTimeMeasure(150.0);
                psv.Unit = model.Instances.New<IfcSIUnit>(siu =>
                {
                    siu.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.TIMEUNIT;
                    siu.Name = IfcSIUnitName.SECOND;
                });
            });
            var ifcPropertyEnumeratedValue = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyEnumeratedValue>(pev =>
            {
                pev.Name = "IfcPropertyEnumeratedValue:Music";
                pev.EnumerationReference = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyEnumeration>(pe =>
                    {
                        pe.Name = "Notes";
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Do"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Re"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Mi"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Fa"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("So"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("La"));
                        pe.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Ti"));
                    });
                pev.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Do"));
                pev.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Re"));
                pev.EnumerationValues.Add(new IfcLabel("Mi"));

            });
            var ifcPropertyBoundedValue = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyBoundedValue>(pbv => 
            {
                pbv.Name = "IfcPropertyBoundedValue:Mass";
                pbv.Description = "";
                pbv.UpperBoundValue = new IfcMassMeasure(5000.0);
                pbv.LowerBoundValue = new IfcMassMeasure(1000.0);
                pbv.Unit = model.Instances.New<IfcSIUnit>(siu =>
                {
                    siu.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.MASSUNIT;
                    siu.Name = IfcSIUnitName.GRAM;
                    siu.Prefix = IfcSIPrefix.KILO;                  
                });
            });

            var definingValues = new List<IfcReal> { new IfcReal(100.0), new IfcReal(200.0), new IfcReal(400.0), new IfcReal(800.0), new IfcReal(1600.0), new IfcReal(3200.0), };
            var definedValues = new List<IfcReal> { new IfcReal(20.0), new IfcReal(42.0), new IfcReal(46.0), new IfcReal(56.0), new IfcReal(60.0), new IfcReal(65.0), };
            var ifcPropertyTableValue = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyTableValue>(ptv =>
            {
                ptv.Name = "IfcPropertyTableValue:Sound";
                foreach (var item in definingValues)
                {
                    ptv.DefiningValues.Add(item);
                }
                foreach (var item in definedValues)
                {
                    ptv.DefinedValues.Add(item);
                }
                ptv.DefinedUnit = model.Instances.New<IfcContextDependentUnit>(cd =>
                {
                    cd.Dimensions = model.Instances.New<IfcDimensionalExponents>(de =>
                    {
                        de.LengthExponent = 0;
                        de.MassExponent = 0;
                        de.TimeExponent = 0;
                        de.ElectricCurrentExponent = 0;
                        de.ThermodynamicTemperatureExponent = 0;
                        de.AmountOfSubstanceExponent = 0;
                        de.LuminousIntensityExponent = 0;
                    });
                    cd.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.FREQUENCYUNIT;
                    cd.Name = "dB";
                });


            });

            var listValues = new List<IfcLabel> { new IfcLabel("Red"), new IfcLabel("Green"), new IfcLabel("Blue"), new IfcLabel("Pink"), new IfcLabel("White"), new IfcLabel("Black"), };
            var ifcPropertyListValue = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyListValue>(plv =>
            {
                plv.Name = "IfcPropertyListValue:Colours";
                foreach (var item in listValues)
                {
                    plv.ListValues.Add(item);
                }
            });

            var ifcMaterial = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterial>(m =>
            {
                m.Name = "Brick";
            });
            var ifcPrValueMaterial = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:Material";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcMaterial;
            });


            var ifcMaterialList = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterialList>(ml =>
                {
                    ml.Materials.Add(ifcMaterial);
                    ml.Materials.Add(model.Instances.New<IfcMaterial>(m =>{m.Name = "Cavity";}));
                    ml.Materials.Add(model.Instances.New<IfcMaterial>(m => { m.Name = "Block"; }));
                });


            var ifcMaterialLayer = model.Instances.New<IfcMaterialLayer>(ml =>
            {
                ml.Material = ifcMaterial;
                ml.LayerThickness = 100.0;
            });
            var ifcPrValueMatLayer = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:MaterialLayer";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcMaterialLayer;
            });

            var ifcDocumentReference = model.Instances.New<IfcDocumentReference>(dr =>
            {
                dr.Name = "Document";
                dr.Location = "c://Documents//TheDoc.Txt";
            });
            var ifcPrValueRef = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:Document";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcDocumentReference;
            });

            var ifcTimeSeries = model.Instances.New<IfcRegularTimeSeries>(ts =>
            {
                ts.Name = "Regular Time Series";
                ts.Description = "Time series of events";
                ts.StartTime = new IfcDateTime("2015-02-14T12:01:01");
                ts.EndTime = new IfcDateTime("2015-05-15T12:01:01");
                ts.TimeSeriesDataType = IfcTimeSeriesDataTypeEnum.CONTINUOUS;
                ts.DataOrigin = IfcDataOriginEnum.MEASURED;
                ts.TimeStep = 604800; //7 days in secs
            });

            var ifcPrValueTimeSeries = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:TimeSeries";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcTimeSeries;
            });

            var ifcAddress = model.Instances.New<IfcPostalAddress>(a =>
            {
                a.InternalLocation = "Room 101";
                a.AddressLines.AddRange(new[] { new IfcLabel("12 New road"), new IfcLabel("DoxField" ) });
                a.Town = "Sunderland";
                a.PostalCode = "DL01 6SX";
            });
            var ifcPrValueAddress = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:Address";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcAddress;
            });
            var ifcTelecomAddress = model.Instances.New<IfcTelecomAddress>(a =>
            {
                a.TelephoneNumbers.Add(new IfcLabel("01325 6589965"));
                a.ElectronicMailAddresses.Add(new IfcLabel("bob@bobsworks.com"));
            });
            var ifcPrValueTelecom = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertyReferenceValue>(prv =>
            {
                prv.Name = "IfcPropertyReferenceValue:Telecom";
                prv.PropertyReference = ifcTelecomAddress;
            });



            //lets create the IfcElementQuantity
            var ifcPropertySet = model.Instances.New<IfcPropertySet>(ps =>
            {              
                ps.Name = "Test:IfcPropertySet";
                ps.Description = "Property Set";
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPropertySingleValue);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPropertyEnumeratedValue);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPropertyBoundedValue);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPropertyTableValue);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPropertyListValue);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueMaterial);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueMatLayer);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueRef);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueTimeSeries);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueAddress);
                ps.HasProperties.Add(ifcPrValueTelecom);             
            });

            //need to create the relationship
            model.Instances.New<IfcRelDefinesByProperties>(rdbp =>
            {                
                rdbp.Name = "Property Association";
                rdbp.Description = "IfcPropertySet associated to wall";
                rdbp.RelatedObjects.Add(wall);
                rdbp.RelatingPropertyDefinition = ifcPropertySet;
            });
        }

        private static void CreateElementQuantity(IfcStore model, IfcWallStandardCase wall)
        {
            //Create a IfcElementQuantity
            //first we need a IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity,first will use IfcQuantityLength
            var ifcQuantityArea = model.Instances.New<IfcQuantityLength>(qa =>
            {
                qa.Name = "IfcQuantityArea:Area";
                qa.Description = "";
                qa.Unit = model.Instances.New<IfcSIUnit>(siu =>
                {
                    siu.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.LENGTHUNIT;
                    siu.Prefix = IfcSIPrefix.MILLI;
                    siu.Name = IfcSIUnitName.METRE;
                });
                qa.LengthValue = 100.0;

            });
            //next quantity IfcQuantityCount using IfcContextDependentUnit
            var ifcContextDependentUnit = model.Instances.New<IfcContextDependentUnit>(cd =>
                {
                    cd.Dimensions = model.Instances.New<IfcDimensionalExponents>(de =>
                        {
                            de.LengthExponent = 1;
                            de.MassExponent = 0;
                            de.TimeExponent = 0;
                            de.ElectricCurrentExponent = 0;
                            de.ThermodynamicTemperatureExponent = 0;
                            de.AmountOfSubstanceExponent = 0;
                            de.LuminousIntensityExponent = 0;
                        });
                    cd.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.LENGTHUNIT;
                    cd.Name = "Elephants";
                });
                var ifcQuantityCount = model.Instances.New<IfcQuantityCount>(qc =>
                {
                    qc.Name = "IfcQuantityCount:Elephant";
                    qc.CountValue = 12;
                    qc.Unit = ifcContextDependentUnit;
                });


             //next quantity IfcQuantityLength using IfcConversionBasedUnit
            var ifcConversionBasedUnit = model.Instances.New<IfcConversionBasedUnit>(cbu =>
            {
                cbu.ConversionFactor = model.Instances.New<IfcMeasureWithUnit>(mu =>
                {
                    mu.ValueComponent = new IfcRatioMeasure(25.4);
                    mu.UnitComponent = model.Instances.New<IfcSIUnit>(siu =>
                    {
                        siu.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.LENGTHUNIT;
                        siu.Prefix = IfcSIPrefix.MILLI;
                        siu.Name = IfcSIUnitName.METRE;
                    });

                });
                cbu.Dimensions = model.Instances.New<IfcDimensionalExponents>(de =>
                {
                    de.LengthExponent = 1;
                    de.MassExponent = 0;
                    de.TimeExponent = 0;
                    de.ElectricCurrentExponent = 0;
                    de.ThermodynamicTemperatureExponent = 0;
                    de.AmountOfSubstanceExponent = 0;
                    de.LuminousIntensityExponent = 0;
                });
                cbu.UnitType = IfcUnitEnum.LENGTHUNIT;
                cbu.Name = "Inch";
            });
            var ifcQuantityLength = model.Instances.New<IfcQuantityLength>(qa =>
            {
                qa.Name = "IfcQuantityLength:Length";
                qa.Description = "";
                qa.Unit = ifcConversionBasedUnit;
                qa.LengthValue = 24.0;
            });

            //lets create the IfcElementQuantity
            var ifcElementQuantity = model.Instances.New<IfcElementQuantity>(eq =>
            {               
                eq.Name = "Test:IfcElementQuantity";
                eq.Description = "Measurement quantity";
                eq.Quantities.Add(ifcQuantityArea);
                eq.Quantities.Add(ifcQuantityCount);
                eq.Quantities.Add(ifcQuantityLength);
            });

            //need to create the relationship
            model.Instances.New<IfcRelDefinesByProperties>(rdbp =>
            {              
                rdbp.Name = "Area Association";
                rdbp.Description = "IfcElementQuantity associated to wall";
                rdbp.RelatedObjects.Add(wall);
                rdbp.RelatingPropertyDefinition = ifcElementQuantity;
            });
        }



    }
}
```

I will also have questions about assigning materials in the future but for now, I really need help with the opening.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Revit or the Revit API, does it? If not, can you please remove the `revit-api` tag?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).